# Who was the mutant who was Storm's stalker?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, character-identification

I remember reading an X-Men comic, about a mutant who was stalking Storm, and was obsessed with her. His power was some sort of energy blast from his hands, I think. He threatened to kill either Colossus or Wolverine, and asked Storm to choose. She chose Wolverine, doubting that Colossus's armor could withstand the blast, and that Wolverine's agility and healing gave him a better chance of survival.

I think I read it about 20 years ago.

Comment: No idea what storyline this is, sounds interesting though.

Comment: Any recollection of when you read this, or description of the character?

Comment: I think I read it roughly 20 years ago. IDK. It has been a very long time.

Comment: No worries. Every little bit helps. Do you recall if the art style seemed contemporary at the time? 20 years ago was roughly the Jim Lee era, which was much different than the Cockrum/Byrne eras and had distinctively different art and color styles.

Comment: Can you recall any details whatsoever? She's had an on again off again relationship with the mutant known as Forge. He was personally responsible for a brief loss of her powers and returning them. As far as a stalker per-se' I'm not exactly sure.  http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070106021445/marveldatabase/images/8/81/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_289.jpg

Comment: The only other things I seem to recall are that I think this mutant was first introduced in the issue, and that the entire story line occurred within the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the comic [Classic X-Men #39](http://uncannyxmen.net/comics/issue/classic-x-men-39) first printed in Nov. 1989; the story is called *"Brigg’s Revenge"*.

The mutant stalker is called [Billy Briggs](http://marvel.wikia.com/Billy_Briggs_%28Earth-616%29).

> Billy Briggs was a homeless mutant living in Manhattan who became
>   enraptured with Storm. He became enraged when she did not notice him,
>   even moreso when a rich man accidentally bumped into him and then
>   smiled at Storm.
>
> Billy followed Storm to Xavier's mansion, where he noticed her
>   friendship with Wolverine and Colossus. Confronting Storm and
>   activating his powers, Billy asked Storm to choose a friend of hers
>   for him to kill. Storm chose Wolverine, knowing his healing factor
>   would save him. Billy's attacked on Wolverine gave Storm and Colossus
>   time to defeat him. Wolverine came close to killing Billy, but Storm
>   called him off; Billy had been through enough already. She sent him to
>   Phoenix, in hope that she could help.
>
> **Powers:** Billy Briggs could release energy from his hands. When he activates his power, his eyes glow yellow.

[image: comic panel]

[image: Comic cover]

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: Wow... Nice job. I don't even remember that one and I consider myself an Xficionado :]